# How to update listbox when I change view in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to update listbox when I'm changing view, but I dont know how to do it. On first page I'm adding some items to list and on second it should to show all items in listbox.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *


tb1 = [["Kofola", "0,5","30"]]


class SeaofBTCapp(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = Label(self, text="Start Page")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        button2 = Button(self, text="add",
                            command=self.add)
        button2.pack()

    def add(self):
        tb1.append(["Radegast", "0,5","30"])
        print(tb1)



class PageOne(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = Label(self, text="Page One!!!")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        self.bill=Listbox(self)
        self.bill.pack()



        for item in tb1:
            co=" ".join(str(x) for x in item)
            self.bill.insert(END, co)

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Put `print('Now in PageOne.__init__()')` before `for item in tb1:` and watch how often it get printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `PageOne` class You are reading the list `tb1` only once, in `__init__()`. To get the changes in `tb1` to be seen in the listbox you also have to update the listbox with the new altered list.

There is also an issue with the list. As it's defined in the global namespace your app will depend on this. I'd suggest you define it in the `SeaofBTCapp()` `__init__()` function and then you can access it through the `controller` object:

```
class SeaofBTCapp(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.tb1 = [["Kofola", "0,5","30"]]
        ... etc ...

class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ... etc ...

    def add(self):
        self.controller.tb1.append(["Radegast", "0,5","30"])
        ... etc ...
```

And then add an `update()` method to the `PageOne()` class which updates the listbox and calls it from the `add()` method. I'm calling by way of controller method `update_pageone()`. See full example below:

```
from tkinter import *

class SeaofBTCapp(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.tb1 = [["Kofola", "0,5","30"]] # Create instance variable tb1
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def update_pageone(self):
        self.frames[PageOne].update()   # Call update on PageOne

class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller    # Remember the controller
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = Label(self, text="Start Page")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                            command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()
        button2 = Button(self, text="add", command=self.add)
        button2.pack()

    def add(self):
        self.controller.tb1.append(["Radegast", "0,5","30"])
        self.controller.update_pageone()    # Asking controller for an update


class PageOne(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller    # Remember the controller
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = Label(self, text="Page One!!!")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        self.bill = Listbox(self)
        self.bill.pack()

        for item in controller.tb1:
            co = " ".join(str(x) for x in item)
            self.bill.insert(END, co)

    def update(self):
        # Delete all from Listbox bill
        self.bill.delete(0, 'end')
        # Add revised table into Listbox bill
        for item in self.controller.tb1:
            co = " ".join(str(x) for x in item)
            self.bill.insert(END, co)

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't know how to call update() method. I know how to call it with button for refresh in PageOne class but don't know how to call without it. Should I call update() in add() method?

Comment: Yes. I have made a full example with the update call. I was not familiar with the page-switching structure so my solution can probably be improved upon.